# How to show SQL query log generated by a RSpec test?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, testing, logging, rspec

I am writing a spec for my rails 3 application. I want to test that db transactions are really working. It would be really helpful to be able to see the sql queries being generated my app while being driven by the spec.

Is there a way to see the queries just like in the rails console?

I'm using Rails 3.0.9, RSpec 2.6, and sqlite (will move to mysql later on)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I turn on SQL debug logging for ActiveRecord in RSpec tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244486/how-do-i-turn-on-sql-debug-logging-for-activerecord-in-rspec-tests)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Put the following code in your specs:

Rails 7.0+

```
ActiveRecord.verbose_query_logs = true
```

Rails 5.2

```
ActiveRecord::Base.verbose_query_logs = true
```

Rails 3.0

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT) if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
```

Thanks to everyone who commented for the Rails updates.

Comment: in your test.rb file you may also need to set `config.log_level = :debug`

Comment: In rails 5.2+, you can also add `ActiveRecord::Base.verbose_query_logs = true` to see the line of code that is triggering each query

Comment: For Rails >= 7.0, the [`ActiveRecord::Base` method has been deprecated](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/c3f43075a3c70c3b11717741426ec38a8d3cd14a). You can instead add `ActiveRecord.verbose_query_logs = true` to see lines triggering each query.

Comment: `verbose_query_logs = true` is not for showing the query log, it is for showing extra information. You still have to add `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` to show the log.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is a combination of:

- Phil's comment above: "in your test.rb file you may also need to set `config.log_level = :debug`"
- and viewing the test's log in another terminal with `tail -f log/test.log`

Answer (score -2):

According to the Rails 5 docs ([Active Record Explain](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#running-explain)). You can now use the explain method. This will only log the queries you specify, but you will not be overwhelmed if you have a large amount of SQL code before your tests.

```
ap Model.explain
```

Comment: `Model.explain` doesn't log queries–it executes the DB's EXPLAIN command, which gives you information about _how_ the query will run. Info like: whether it uses an index, how many rows of the DB the query will need to examine, etc.