# Rails testing error: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

Users can vote for Posts through a has_many association. I'm getting this error from running tests:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer
```

From this test:

```
test "should unvote a post the standard way" do
  @user.vote(@post_2)
  postvoterelationship = @user.active_post_vote_relationships.find_by(voted_id: @post_2.id)
  assert_difference '@user.postvoting.count', -1 do
    delete postvoterelationship_path(postvoterelationship)
  end
end
```

postvoterelationships_controller.rb

```
def destroy
  @user = Postvoterelationship.find(params[:id]).voter
  @post = Postvoterelationship.find_by(params[:id]).voted
  @user.unvote(@post)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      redirect_to @user
    end
    format.js
  end
end # destroy
```

routes.rb

```
resources :postvoterelationships,  only: [:create, :destroy]
```

postvoterelationship.rb

```
class Postvoterelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :voter, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :voted, class_name: "Post"
  validates  :voter_id, presence: true
  validates  :voted_id, presence: true
end
```

user.rb

```
has_many :postvoting, through: :active_post_vote_relationships, source: :voted
```

EDIT:

Server logs:

```
Started DELETE "/postvoterelationships/207" for ::1 at 2015-06-16 21:02:07 +0100
Processing by PostvoterelationshipsController#destroy as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bP17sWN2k6lFqnNxEa6NNEO5yWXkGopi9PSXLIEKzooR3XUfF4chhS3+W+9WP8EB3GwzfhsauAyPiIp1/kkh9A==", "commit"=>"Unvote", "id"=>"207"}
Character Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "characters".* FROM "characters" WHERE "characters"."callsign" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["callsign", "bazzer"]]
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Postvoterelationship Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "postvoterelationships".* FROM "postvoterelationships" WHERE "postvoterelationships"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 207]]
Character Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "characters".* FROM "characters" WHERE "characters"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Postvoterelationship Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  "postvoterelationships".* FROM "postvoterelationships" WHERE (207) LIMIT 1
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer
LINE 1: ...ationships".* FROM "postvoterelationships" WHERE (207) LIMIT...
                                                         ^
: SELECT  "postvoterelationships".* FROM "postvoterelationships" WHERE (207) LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 4.3ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer
LINE 1: ...ationships".* FROM "postvoterelationships" WHERE (207) LIMIT...
                                                         ^
: SELECT  "postvoterelationships".* FROM "postvoterelationships" WHERE (207) LIMIT 1):
app/controllers/postvoterelationships_controller.rb:24:in `destroy'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried to look at the SQL queries made? You can show them in test environment, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884408/how-to-show-sql-query-log-generated-by-a-rspec-test).

And, in `postvoterelationships_controller.rb`, I think:

```
  @post = Postvoterelationship.find_by(params[:id]).voted
```

should be:

```
  @post = Postvoterelationship.find(params[:id]).voted
```

Comment: That was it. Should have been `find`, not `find_by`. I am a halfwit. Thank you vmarquet.

Comment: I had a very similar bug. I did want to use `find_by`; in my case, the solution was to change to: `.find_by(id: params[:id])`