# Rails not porting SQLITE localhost to Heroku PGSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, heroku, rails-activerecord

Following a tutorial on rails and I get this error when attempting a `method: :delete` action.

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer`

This is my destroy method.

```
  def destroy
@user_stock = current_user.user_stocks.where(stock_id: params[:id]).first
@user_stock.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to my_portfolio_path, notice: "#{@user_stock.stock.ticker} was removed from portfolio." }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end
```

I read a question on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873680/rails-testing-error-argument-of-where-must-be-type-boolean-not-type-integer) about `find` and `find_by` needing to be used right but it just confused me.

**UserStocksController**

```html
class UserStocksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user_stock, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /user_stocks
  # GET /user_stocks.json
  def index
    @user_stocks = UserStock.all
  end

  # GET /user_stocks/1
  # GET /user_stocks/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /user_stocks/new
  def new
    @user_stock = UserStock.new
  end

  # GET /user_stocks/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /user_stocks
  # POST /user_stocks.json
  def create
    if params[:stock_id].present?
      @user_stock = UserStock.new(stock_id: params[:stock_id], user: current_user)
    else
      stock = Stock.find_by_ticker(params[:stock_ticker])
      if stock
        @user_stock = UserStock.new(user: current_user, stock: stock)
      else
        stock = Stock.new_from_lookup(params[:stock_ticker])
        if stock.save
          @user_stock = UserStock.new(user:current_user, stock: stock)
        else
          @user_stock = nil
          flash[:error] = "Stock is not available"
        end
      end
    end
    
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_stock.save
        format.html { redirect_to my_portfolio_path, notice: "Stock #{@user_stock.stock.ticker} was saved" }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user_stock }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user_stock.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /user_stocks/1
  # PATCH/PUT /user_stocks/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_stock.update(user_stock_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user_stock, notice: 'User stock was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user_stock }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user_stock.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /user_stocks/1
  # DELETE /user_stocks/1.json
  def destroy
    @user_stock = current_user.user_stocks.where(stock_id: params[:id]).first
    @user_stock.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to my_portfolio_path, notice: "#{@user_stock.stock.ticker} was removed from portfolio." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_user_stock
     @user_stock = UserStock.find_by(params[:id])
   end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_stock_params
      params.require(:user_stock).permit(:user_id, :stock_id)
    end
end
```

**The `my_portfolio` view renders a partial `_list`**

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Symbol</th>
   <th>Current Price</th>
   <% if @user.id == current_user.id%>
   <th>Actions</th>
   <%end%>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <%@user_stocks.each do |us|%>
  <tr>
   <td><%=us.name%></td>
   <td><%=us.ticker%></td>
   <td><%=us.price%></td>
   <% if @user.id == current_user.id%>
   <td>
    <%= link_to 'Delete', user_stock_path(us), :method => :delete,
                  :data => {:confirm => "You sure you want to delete #{us.name} from your portfolio?"},
                 :class => "btn btn-xs btn-danger"%>
            </td>
   <%end%>
  </tr>
  <%end%>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably your `set_user_stock` method:

```
def set_user_stock
  @user_stock = UserStock.find_by(params[:id])
end
```

`UserStock.find_by(params[:id])` is just a shorter way of saying:

```
UserStock.where(params[:id]).first
```

So if `params[:id]` is, say, `6`, you'll end up sending this SQL to the database:

```
select *
from user_stocks
where 6
```

and there's your error: `6` is not a boolean value in SQL and `where 6` doesn't make sense. SQLite's interpretation of SQL is rather loose so it will accept nonsense like `where 6` but PostgreSQL rightly complains.

There are two lessons here:

1. Your `set_user_stock` method should look like:

   ```
   def set_user_stock
     @user_stock = UserStock.find(params[:id])
   end
   ```

   or

   ```
   def set_user_stock
     @user_stock = UserStock.find_by(:id => params[:id])
   end
   ```

   Use the `find` version if you're expecting to always call `set_user_stock` with a valid `params[:id]` and `find_by` if you want to deal with `@user_stock.nil?` yourself.
2. Never ever develop on top of one database and deploy on another. Doubly so if you're trying to develop on SQLite and deploy on anything else. You should **always** develop, test, and deploy using the same database (all the way down to the database version), ActiveRecord will not protect you from any of the difficult parts of database portability.

Answer (score 1):

Ok from what I have this my guess. Again, you only posted a partial so I am not sure how this all relates but my guess is that you add the id like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', user_stock_path(id: us.id), :method => :delete,
                                                       :data => {:confirm => "You sure you want to delete #{us.name} from your portfolio?"},
                                                       :class => "btn btn-xs btn-danger"%>
```

Comment: undefined method stock_id

Comment: Can you post your entire controller ?

Comment: just did that in my question

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer still in heroku

Comment: Can you try the latest answer. If it does not work , please post your full trace

Comment: undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass now i guess @user_stock isn't getting anything with your latest answer

Comment: Ok it would have been better if you posted your full trace. I edited my answer again. Try it again

Comment: The problem now is that it will delete the first stock in the display instead of the actual stock i click delete on

Comment: Ok show your views too. The information you have shared so far is insufficient for us to help you

Comment: Ok check my answer again

Comment: Still removes the first stock in the display

Comment: having ATuser_stock = current_user.user_stocks.where(stock_id: params[:id]).first as well as ATuser_stock.delete together works in local dev (SQLite) but not in Heroku production(PostgresSQL) so there has to be something wrong with the first line.